# Write something in First and Last cell of a Column in dataframe. Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

In a dataframe
write x in first cell of column C,
write y in last cell of column C

Present work around involves importing csv in df, retain first and last row delete others, some calculations, using conditions np.select.

Dataframe will have several rows and columns and will be imported from various csv files with different rows and column lengths.

Is there a less messy option, so that the deleting rows etc is avoided ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to index by column name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [0, 1, 2, 7],
        'B': [4, 5, 6, 8],
        'C': ['', '', '', '']
    }
)
```

```
   A  B C
0  0  4
1  1  5
2  2  6
3  7  8
```

```
first_idx = df.index[0]
last_idx = df.index[-1]

df.loc[first_idx, 'C'] = 'x'
df.loc[last_idx, 'C'] = 'y'
```

```
   A  B  C
0  0  4  x
1  1  5
2  2  6
3  7  8  y
```

Answer (score 2):

Select first row `0` and last column `-1` or last row `-1` and last column `-1` and set values in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[0, -1] = 'x'
df.iloc[-1, -1] = 'y'
```

Or in [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
df.iat[0, -1] = 'x'
df.iat[-1, -1] = 'y'
```

For column `C` get position by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
pos = df.columns.get_loc('C')
df.iloc[0, pos] = 'x'
df.iloc[-1, pos] = 'y'
```

---

```
pos = df.columns.get_loc('C')
df.iat[0, pos] = 'x'
df.iat[-1, pos] = 'y'
```